# Operaciones con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema con este código intento realizar una operación que la resta del resultado de dos `inputs` se muestre en otro `input` pero al estar vacíos al principio me marca el error NaN solo me da el resultado al ejecutar nuevamente el script

```js
function calcular() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.capacidad.value);
  var n3 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.fijador.value);
  var n5 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.dosificacion.value);
  // alerta
  if (isNaN(n1)) {
    alert('Ingresa el capacidad');
  } else {
    document.dosificacion.esencia.value = (n1 * n5) / (100).toFixed();
    var n2 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.esencia.value);
    document.dosificacion.esencia.value += " g.";
    document.dosificacion.fijador.value = (n1 * .08).toFixed() + " g.";
    document.dosificacion.perfumol.value = (n1 - n2 - n3).toFixed() + " g.";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="dosificacion">
  <div>
    <input class="capacidad" type="text" name="capacidad"><br>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="esencia" type="text" name="esencia"><br>

  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="perfumol" type="text" name="perfumol"><br>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="fijador" type="text" name="fijador"><br>

  </div>
  <div>
    <p></p>
    <select class="concentracion" name="dosificacion">
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="boton1" type="button" value="dosificacion" onclick="calcular()">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que deseas lograr?

Comment: es una tabla de dosificaciones, de envases al poner la capacidad del envase el código calcula cuanto hay que agregar de cada producto y el select es para elegir el tipo de concentración que necesita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que quieres utilizar el valor de n3 antes que el `input` tenga un valor, yo te recomiendo que realices todos tus cálculos con variables *locales* y al final las pongas en los `inputs`

```js
function calcular() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.capacidad.value);

  // alerta
  if (isNaN(n1)) {
    alert('Ingresa el capacidad');
    return;
  }
  
  var n5 = parseInt(document.dosificacion.dosificacion.value);
  var esencia = (n1 * n5) / (100).toFixed();
  var n2 = parseInt(esencia);
  var fijador = (n1 * .08).toFixed();
  var perfumol = (n1 - n2 - fijador).toFixed();

  document.dosificacion.esencia.value = esencia + " g.";
  document.dosificacion.fijador.value = fijador + " g.";
  document.dosificacion.perfumol.value = perfumol + " g.";

}
```

```html
<form name="dosificacion">
  <div>
    <input class="capacidad" type="text" name="capacidad"><br>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="esencia" type="text" name="esencia"><br>

  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="perfumol" type="text" name="perfumol"><br>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="fijador" type="text" name="fijador"><br>

  </div>
  <div>
    <p></p>
    <select class="concentracion" name="dosificacion">
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <input class="boton1" type="button" value="dosificacion" onclick="calcular()">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias es lo que necesitaba, excelente día

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus aportaciones excelente día a todos

Comment: a qui les dejo el link de como quedo gracias por su apoyo http://www.gloriaperfumes.com.mx/concentracion/dosificaciones.html

Answer (score 0):

Puede hacer una funcion para asegurar que recibe numeros con JQuery

```
function Quita_Moneda(n){
    n=String(n);
    var s=n.replace("$","");
    while(s.toString().indexOf(",")!=-1) s=s.replace(",","");
    s=parseFloat(s);
    if(isNaN(s))s=0;
    return s;
}

var numero=Quita_Moneda($("input").val());
```